# Grub timeout set to 30 after upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade

Today I ran a routine "apt upgrade", and it upgraded several GRUB-related packages. I am using GRUB 2.02 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

After this, the GRUB menu appears on every boot with a 30 second timeout.

Previously, the GRUB menu was hidden.

Any ideas as to what might cause this? My /etc/default/grub is below.

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="--verbose nosplash debug"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: This is a bug that has been reported and fixed. It will come soon to everybody: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1814403

Comment: From the  thread above it seem like it's not been fixed for UEFI and LVM. Reducing GRUB_TIMEOUT doesn't change anything. Still getting 30 second wait.

Comment: @Ubuntu_enthusiast Great! I have UEFI *and* LVM! Lol.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This thread [grub-recordfail-broken-regarding-lvm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120948/grub-recordfail-broken-regarding-lvm) tries to get to the bottom of the problem.

If you are looking for a quick fix, you can

```
sudo sh -c 'echo GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=5 >> /etc/default/grub';
sudo update-grub;
```

- thank @borislav for pointing out `sudo grub-install;` is not needed for configuring Grub menu timeout

Comment: are you sure that `sudo grub-install` is needed? In my system (elementary OS based on Ubuntu 18.04) execution of grub-install finishesh with update-grub, also why it have to be done when only this line into config file do the job?

Comment: @Borislav you are right, grub-install only installs MBR and is not needed for the Grub menu timeout

Answer (score 11):

It worked for me to add

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
```

in /etc/default/grub

and then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Ubuntu 23, it works for me also. But why [usual way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/762488/how-disable-grub-timeout-30s) doesn't work?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.  This fixed it for me:

In a terminal window run:

```
sudo sed -i "/recordfail_broken=/{s/1/0/}" /etc/grub.d/00_header
```

then

```
sudo update-grub
```

courtesy of: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=287026