# Reduce GRUB's contdown time on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: grub2, timeout

Can't reduce the countdown time from the default 30 seconds in grub 2.04. I am running a fresh Xubuntu 20.04 LTS, with the addition that I've installed newer kernel images, to get access to my CPU temperature.

What I've tried:

- changed `GRUB_TIMEOUT` in `/etc/default/grub`
- set quickboot to 0 and changed `timeout` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264119/how-to-change-grub-timeout-in-ubuntu-20-04)
- changed `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` to `menu` and `countdown` as proposed in [here](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-change-the-grub-menu-timeout-at-boot/) and in another link I do not find at the moment.
- Commented out the last line (`adjust_timeout`) in `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`

After all of these steps I've run `sudo update-grub`, which run without any error.

My `/etc/default/grub` file without comments:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

---

**Edit**

Right after I've written the question down, I've made another try. I grep-ed all files in `/etc/grub.d` which had the string 30 in it. Only `00_header` has it at two places. The big part of this file is a `make_timeout` function. This part of the script is reached only if `"$recordfail_broken" = 1`  or `"\${recordfail}" = 1`. So it indicates that something went wrong, and I probably should debug it, though I have not experienced any drawbacks yet. For the time being I've changed those values from 30 to 3.

Comment: Have you run `update-grub` which re-creates the `grub.cfg` file from the recorded settings?

Comment: I have searched the web for "recordfail_broken" and had a few results. Some from them: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120948/grub-recordfail-broken-regarding-lvm and  https://askubuntu.com/questions/202309/cannot-get-grub-menu-to-timeout-or-go-away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these commands as root

```
echo 'GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT' >> /etc/default/grub
update-grub
```

There was a regression added at some point in 18.04 that caused grub to trigger recordfail if your `/boot` partition was an LVM volume, IIRC.

I would have thought it would be fixed for 20.04, but I'm not sure.  Here are some of the bug reports I saved

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1814403
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1815002
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1800722

Answer (score 0):

The GUI way:
install grub customizer using the commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt update
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

In the application navigate to general-settings>>default-boot-entry-after
set it to as many seconds as you wish.