# Slow boot/grub menu

Tags: boot, grub2

My Ubuntu 18.04 loads really slow. At first the GRUB menu always showed for 30 seconds on every startup. Fiddling around with

```
/etc/default/grub
```

was little help. I found the [suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114797/grub-timeout-set-to-30-after-upgrade?newreg=22644ee7b5c44a71b67969b69af6ff7c) to run

```
sudo sed -i "/recordfail_broken=/{s/1/0/}" /etc/grub.d/00_header
```

Now the GRUB menu doesn't show, but instead there is a blank screen for 10 seconds before the system starts.
The problem is that I am not sure what the above command does, so now I don't know how to reverse it and I still haven't solved the slow boot problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

```
sudo sed -i "/recordfail_broken=/{s/1/0/}" /etc/grub.d/00_header
```

replaces the string `recordfail_broken=1` with `recordfail_broken=0` in the file `/etc/grub.d/00_header`

To revert the change, you can run

```
sudo sed -i "/recordfail_broken=/{s/0/1/}" /etc/grub.d/00_header
```

which will do the opposite of the former command, it replaces the string `recordfail_broken=0` with `recordfail_broken=1` in the file `/etc/grub.d/00_header`

You will have to run `sudo update-grub` to make the change take effect.

The [suggested solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1114878/590937) you mentioned is a workaround and is not a clean solution. You should investigate why the problem appears. I think that the origin of your problem is that your `/boot`-directory resides in a filesystem Grub can't write to, e.g. `btrfs`.

Comment: Thanks! I also solved the solution with the grub menu: I just had to add GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0 in /etc/default/grub